# Another Google maps question about how to remove the A and B icon in ver 2.*

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-2

I have done vast research on this topic without much success. I must point out that I am a real beginner of google maps and javascript. 
I am trying to remove the A and B icons that appear on google map when asking for directions.

I am in creating a customised layout for the directions from a great tutorial but I am struggling in removing the A and B symbol from the map itself.
Any help will be apprecaited as I am banging my head against a brick wall.

The Code currently

```
 if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

  var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
  var dirn = new GDirections(map);
//var dirn = new GDirections(map).setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );


  GEvent.addListener(dirn,"error", function() {
    alert("Directions Failed: "+dirn.getStatus().code);
  });

 dirn.load("from: <% Response.Write homlat %>,<% Response.Write homlng %> to: "+Slat+","+Slongtit+"", {getSteps:true});


  function customPanel(map,mapname,dirn,div) {
    var html = "";



    function waypoint(point, type, address) {
      var target = '"' + mapname+".showMapBlowup(new GLatLng("+point.toUrlValue(6)+"))"  +'"';
      html += '<table style="border: 3px solid silver; margin: 10px 0px; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); border-collapse: collapse; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">';
      html += '  <tr style="cursor: pointer;" onclick='+target+'>';
      html += '    <td style="padding: 4px 15px 0px 5px; vertical-align: middle; width: 20px;">';



     html += '      <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/icon-dd-' +type+ '-trans.png">'
      html +=       type;
      html += '    <\/td>';
      html += '    <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;">';
      html +=        address;
      html += '    <\/td>';
      html += '  <\/tr>';
      html += '<\/table>';
    }


    function routeDistance(dist) {
      html += '<div style="text-align: right; padding-bottom: 0.3em;">' + dist + '<\/div>';
    }      

    function detail(point, num, description, dist) {
      var target = '"' + mapname+".showMapBlowup(new GLatLng("+point.toUrlValue(6)+"))"  +'"';
      html += '<table style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">';
      html += '  <tr style="cursor: pointer;" onclick='+target+'>';
      html += '    <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(205, 205, 205); margin: 0px; padding: 0.3em 3px; vertical-align: top; text-align: right;">';
      html += '      <a href="javascript:void(0)"> '+num+'. <\/a>';
      html += '    <\/td>';
      html += '    <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(205, 205, 205); margin: 0px; padding: 0.3em 3px; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">';
      html +=        description;
      html += '    <\/td>';
      html += '    <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(205, 205, 205); margin: 0px; padding: 0.3em 3px 0.3em 0.5em; vertical-align: top; text-align: right;">';
      html +=        dist;
      html += '    <\/td>';
      html += '  <\/tr>';
      html += '<\/table>';
    }

    function copyright(text) {
      html += '<div style="font-size: 0.86em;">' + text + "<\/div>";
    }


    for (var i=0; i<dirn.getNumRoutes(); i++) {
      if (i==0) {
       // var type="play";
      var type="<img src='map_images/man_image.png'>";
      } else {
        var type="pause";
      }
      var route = dirn.getRoute(i);
      var geocode = route.getStartGeocode();
      var point = route.getStep(0).getLatLng();


     waypoint(point, type, addsrch);
    routeDistance(route.getDistance().html+" (about "+route.getDuration().html+")"); 

      for (var j=0; j<route.getNumSteps(); j++) {
        var step = route.getStep(j);
        detail(step.getLatLng(), j+1, step.getDescriptionHtml(), step.getDistance().html);
      }
    }

    var geocode = route.getEndGeocode();
    var point = route.getEndLatLng();
  waypoint(point, stopIcons[Sicon], Sbuild);
    copyright(dirn.getCopyrightsHtml());


    div.innerHTML = html;

  }
GEvent.addListener(dirn,"load", function() {
    setTimeout('customPanel(map,"map",dirn,document.getElementById("path"))', 1);
  });

}
```

I am using Google maps API ver 2.*. Many Thanks for anyone who helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have direct access to the markers in this case because they are automatically generated when directions are generated.
You have to suppress them with a specific function called DirectionsRenderer

```
//existing code
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
var dirn = new GDirections(map);

//additional code
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionsDisplay.suppressMarkers = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply stephen. I tried replacing existing code with your line but with no success. I think it maybe because I'm using googles 2.* API rather than there 3.0 API as could only find suppressMarkers in v3.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I'll try and search for a solution for you, meanwhile out of interest, why don't you move to v3?

Comment: I will do eventually, just the site that I am working on is now overdue and most of what I have done is for v2.*. Many Thanks Stephen you are a Star.

Comment: try  var marker = new GMarker();
  GMap2.addOverlay(marker);
  marker.hide();   - put that in place of the code i supplied above, it might hide the markers for you.  I cant test these out for you as I don't have access to a test server at the moment.

Comment: I gave it a go stephen and placed it in a variety of places within the code but with no success. I thought that might of worked.

Comment: Other than that I'm not sure, you probably have already but have a read of http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GDirections  hopefully another SO member will pick up on this

Comment: Thanks for giving up your time and trying to get a remedy Stephen. I appreciate it.